# HTML 5 - load text from text files

Tags: html

I am facing problem in HTML 5. I need to statically load data into web page from local saved files. Up to now, I have been only able to load data via < input type="file" id="fileinput" / > but I want to load data from static location, which never changes. How to do that? And is there any way how to determine, whether some local file was changed from previous version?

Thanks

Comment: by "local" you mean on your computer (and not on the server)? just to get this straight..

Comment: on local computer, which acts as a server

Comment: If the server is on the same machine as the file, you should be telling your web server to load the file data and put it into the html page.

Answer (score 0):

no, this isn't possible if by 'local', you mean a file at /home/waypoint/somefile.txt. You can make a 'link' with the filesystem api (if you selected it in an input field, for instance), which is valid to do computations with it (to read it, write to it, display it in img,etc). But it is deleted/unvalid, as soon as the window closes. If you could just magically "read" any local file via javascript which resides on the file system, who would stop google to read out your /etc/passwd file?

if your local computer is also your server and therefor your server-side code has access to the local file /home/waypoint/somefile.txt, your app can get it via ajax. Checking if the file exists, would be done the same way.